# ffmpeg convert non transparent pixel to white

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert all non-transparent pixels of an image to white using the geq filter in ffmpeg:
`ffmpeg -y -i in.png -vf "format=rgba,geq='r=if(lt(alpha(X,Y),10),255):g=if(lt(alpha(X,Y),10),255):b=if(lt(alpha(X,Y),10),255):a=alpha(X,Y)'" x.png`

But ffmpeg is giving me black pixels instead of white. Any ideas what is going on?

in.png:

[image]

out.png:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The two operand `if` expression returns 0 if the condition isn't met. You need the three operand version.

```
if(lt(alpha(X,Y),10),255,p(X,Y))
```

Comment: Thanks, the final one that worked for me is: ```ffmpeg -y -i in.png -vf "format=rgba,geq='r=if(gt(alpha(X,Y),128),255,0):g=if(gt(alpha(X,Y),128),255,0):b=if(gt(alpha(X,Y),128),255,0):a=if(gt(alpha(X,Y),250),255,0)'" x.png && open x.png```

Comment: @user984896 – [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)